# In a Laravel Project, where is the default location for uploaded files?

Tags: laravel, file

If I was to upload an image or audio file to my server using Ajax, where is the file data stored by default without using the `move` method? Is it in the `Storage/framework/cache/data` folder?

**UPDATE**

To further elaborate, I want to know, if i upload a file via ajax ( lets say an audio file ), and inside the controller function in which the request goes to, theres is **NO CODE IN THE BLOCK, JUST BLANK** where does that uploaded file go?

example of function:

```
public function processUploadedFile(Request $Request) {
 // blank block, no code to affect file
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the code you're using to store the file?

Comment: @Devon please check my updates question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

You would need post the move code that you have used. So, we can know about the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to **storage/app/public**. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

php artisan storage:link

Of course, once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

echo asset('storage/file.txt');

Make use of helper to upload file

Check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads

**Please** mark/upvote if this finds helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends really. But most likely it will be stored in the `storage` folder. If your user would need to access the files uploaded, you must store the file in `storage/app/public`. To be able to access that folder, perform `php artisan storage:link` which will create a symbolic link accessible from `public` folder.

Let's say I wanted to upload a file file variable name `avatar`.

`$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('public/avatars');`

To access the retrieve the file in client side just call `asset('storage/avatars');`

Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem